# Drop Down not showing in TinyMCE Editor with react modal

Tags: reactjs, tinymce, react-modal

I have used a react modal to display the tinyMCE editor.When I load the editor in that modal the editors appears.The issue is the drop downs within the tinyMCE are not working.

```
EX: block_formats drop down not working
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the CSS Z-index. There was a conflict between the project bootstrap CSS z-index and the TinyMCE CSS z-index.